# Graphlab - How to set the number of trees parameter in random forest classifier

Tags: graphlab

I am training a random forest classifier :

```
model = gl.random_forest_classifier.create(train, target = 'label',row_subsample = 0.5, column_subsample = 0.75, validation_set=validation, metric="auc",  max_iterations=10, max_depth = 15)
```

How can I set the number of trees parameter? It's a binary classification problem and the documentation says:

> max_iterations : The maximum number of iterations to perform. For multi-class classification with K classes, each iteration will create K-1 trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"The `num_trees` keyword argument is deprecated. Please use the `max_iterations` argument instead. Any value provided for `num_trees` will be used in place of `max_iterations`."***

So, adjust the ***`max_iterations`*** also means adjust the the number of trees parameter.

Comment: Could you please provide any reference for this?

Comment: @Tarun  
You can open the source code of random_forest_classifier.py at location \Lib\site-packages\graphlab\toolkits\classifier, the line number 653-655.